# Redirect away from www to non-www domain on nginx from behind HAproxy

Tags: nginx, web-server, web-hosting, haproxy

I'm a bit confused. I have nginx running on a port other than 80.

```
# part of nginx.conf
server {
  listen  7000;
  include /etc/nginx/my_app.conf;
}
```

That's because my HAProxy is running on 80 on the same server.

```
# Approximate haproxy.cfg
listen foo 0.0.0.0:80
  option forwardfor
    server web01 web01:7000 maxconn 25000 check
```

How do I make nginx serve a redirect from www.example.com to example.com?

I tried the following, but nginx complains that it can't listen on 80 (which makes sense, since haproxy is listening there.)

```
server {
  server_name  www.example.com;
  rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Since nginx cascades down the defined servers, I can add a more specific server declaration above the one I had. In my case it's the following.

```
server {
  listen 7000;
  server_name www.example.com;
  rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 7000;
  include /etc/nginx/my_app.conf;
}
```

I can have multiple declaration listening on the same port, but the first one will catch the www subdomain and serve a redirect, while the second one actually serves the app.